# Statically typed open source cross platform modern programming language

Tags: open-source, cross-platform, static-typing

May be it's a silly question. Is there an alternative to Java and .NET platform?

Which:

- Is a **programming language** itself. Language ports unless they become dominant are not really successfull IMO.
- May have it's own **execution platform** like JVM, which is a big plus. But interpreter is also ok.
- Is **statically typed**.
- Is **open source** and developed by **open community**.
- Is **cross platform** like Java: compile once, run everywhere.
- Is modern: multiparadigm (OOP and generic, functional is a plus), concurrent (at least allowing to write concurrently), garbage collection is a plus, reflection is a plus.

I'd be glad to know about unpopular or experimental languages which satisfy this criteria too. Dead languages are not ok.

A language for which all of the above (subjective) conditions is **true** probably falls in one of two categories

1. Statically typed interpreted language project. Which would provide cross platform interpreter and library.
2. Java-like language but with two distinctions: not being Java port and developed by community.

Comment: Why the need for "statically typed"?

Comment: Today's unpopular or experimental language has a good chance of becoming tomorrow's dead language.

Comment: @Ocaso: I'm the Visual Studio user and used to think that static typing saves my time because compiler checks type mismatch errors (part of) and IDE helps refactoring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be scala. It runs on JVM, it's statically typed. Lift is web framework developed in scala. I heard IDE support is not good. IntelliJ IDE may be best one to consider.

Answer (score 2):

[Haxe](https://haxe.org/documentation/introduction/language-features.html) is a decent language. Its initial popularity came from it being used as a replacement for ActionScript, but I think it's growing beyond that.

Initially, it could be compiled to either ActionScript or [Neko VM](https://nekovm.org/) (a VM written by the author of Haxe) but now the compiler supports [several more targets](https://haxe.org/documentation/introduction/compiler-targets.html) including JavaScript and C++.

Answer (score 1):

look at GO from google.

http://code.google.com/p/go/

Comment: See http://go-lang.cat-v.org/os-ports for the porting efforts and supported platforms.

Comment: Go is a compiled language. I do not think it supports compile once - run everywhere paradigm.

Comment: Ahh, my mistake I somehow missed the compile once, run everywhere. Is .NET compile once run everywhere?

Comment: no, .NET is not, Java wins here. Looking for the perfect language I've tried to focus things most important to me.

Comment: Mike, I have recently been tasked with writing an app in Flex, Actionscript 3 from Adobe. It ticks some of your boxes, unfortunately not the opensource one, since it's an Adobe product. Wish me luck, we are moving from a fully functional, working .NET GUI to a Flex GUI.

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Probably, [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) itself with supported languages if *not considered* as a substitution to the .NET Framework.

- There's C#. It's not a C# port, it is fully compatible C# implementation. And it is statically typed.
- There is a cross-platform execution runtime. Major platforms will run Mono code without recompilation.
- It looks like it's totally open source.

**2)** There's [Shen](http://www.shenlanguage.org/index.html) around. Haven't tried it myself but looks like it is conforms to question requirements.